# No enclosing instance of the type AnimationTimer is accessible in scope

Tags: javafx

I am using JavaFX to create my own version of the Pong game. And after displaying the final score, clicking the given button to return to the main menu, I am trying to start back up my AnimationTimer, or loop. However, I am getting this error, "No enclosing instance of the type AnimationTimer is accessible in scope". How do I restart the AnimationTimer within the .setOnAction of the button?

Here is the code for my AnimationTimer

```
new AnimationTimer() {
        public void handle(long now) {
            if(playing) {
                x += dx;
                y += dy;

                if ( x < 0 || x+ball.getWidth() > scene.getWidth() )
                    dx = -dx;
                if (y < 0 )
                    dy = -dy;

                if(y > scene.getHeight() && lives > 0) {
                    x = 400;
                    y = 400;
                    dx = 5;
                    dy = -5;
                    lives-=5;
                    life.setText("Lives: " + lives);
                }

                if(left && pX > 5) {
                    pX -= speed;
                } else if(right && pX+paddle.getWidth() < scene.getWidth() - 5) {
                    pX += speed;
                }


                if (x > pX-40 && x < pX + paddle.getWidth() && y == pY-paddle.getHeight()-15) {
                    dy = -dy;
                    score+=1;
                    scores.setText("Score: " + score);
                }



                life.relocate(10, 10);
                ball.relocate(x, y);
                paddle.relocate(pX, pY);
            }

            if(lives == 0) {
                playing = false;
                gameover = true;
                this.stop();
                root.getChildren().removeAll(paddle, ball, scores, life);
                finalScore.setText("" + score);
                root.getChildren().add(finalScore);
                root.getChildren().add(returnToMain);
                returnToMain.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        playing = false;
                        gameover = false;
                        root.getChildren().addAll(start, pong);
                        root.getChildren().removeAll(finalScore, returnToMain);

                        AnimationTimer.this.start();
                    }
                });
            }       
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: That just seems like the wrong place to be defining the event handler for `returnToMain`, but can't you just replace `AnimationTimer.this.start()` with `start()`?

Comment: Yes this works, however when I do this, I can no longer seemingly remove my finalScore, and returnToMain

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "return to main"

Comment: Actually, I guess I don't really know what you mean by "no longer". The previous version didn't actually compile, so you couldn't even run it. So it certainly wasn't doing anything else before. I think it sounds like you have a different issue entirely which only becomes apparent when you fix the first one.